# Remove duplicate rows with one different value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with duplicate rows except for one value. I want to filter them out and only keep the row with the higher value.

```
User_ID - Skill - Year_used
1 - skill_a - 2017
1 - skill_b - 2015
1 - skill_a - 2018
2 - skill_c - 2011
```

etc.

So for example rows with skill_a and the same User_ID need to be compared and only the one with the latest year should be kept.

```
transform.('count')
```

Only gives me the amount of rows of the group by User_ID.

```
value_counts()
```

Only gives me a series I can't merge back to the df.

Nay ideas?

Thank you

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['User_ID,'Skill'],keep='last')` - does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `drop_duplicates` by sorting a column to keep `max`

```
df = df.sort_values('Year_used').drop_duplicates(['User_ID','Skill'], keep='last')
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the `Skill` and keep the `max` `Year_used`:

```
df.groupby(['User_ID','Skill']).Year_used.max().reset_index()

     User_ID    Skill  Year_used
0        1  skill_a       2018
1        1  skill_b       2015
2        2  skill_c       2011
```